# PHP single property getter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create a getter to a derived class, like this:

```
public function __get($property) {
    if($property != "_user")
        return $this->$property;

    $this->get_current_user();
    return $this->_user;
}
```

This getter is meant to only serve the "_user" property of my class, which is the only property of my derived class; (If trying to access the `_user`, first find the user in the database, then return it, or `get_current_user` throws an exception)

However, when executing this code, I get an error from the great-grand-parent class:

> Cannot assign by reference to overloaded object

I am not allowed to change that class, as it is the core of Codeigniter. Is there a proper way to do something like `__get_property`, so I could do `__get__user`?

Comment: Can I just point out that `return $this->$property;` is a recursive call to `__get` that will never terminate?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I read the documentation again. No, it is not a recursive call, as (1) Overloading not used on declared properties, (2) on undeclared, or private properties -  Overloading only used on this when accessed outside the class. Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get first example

Comment: Huh. Fair enough.